# How to link N*M cells in MS-excel? (F4 function for $ in a matrix)

Tags: microsoft-excel, links, worksheet-function

I need to link several cells from a matrix.

How can I do that? Normally I use to clikc F4 to insert $ symbols for lines/columns, but in this case I have to put it in each cell. Is there a shortest way?

Comment: Is this a single array formula? Is it a formula that has been auto-filled (dragged down)? Or are these completely independent formulae?

Comment: It is a simple link so: A1=sheet1!A1 - A2=sheet1!A2 - B1=sheet1!B1 - B2=sheet1!B2 ...

Comment: Your question is very unclear to me. `$` in formulas usually means an absolute reference. Not using `$` gives you a relative reference.

Comment: So click on cell A1, press F4, and then drag it down and across.

Comment: @Raystafarian :  I have to make several operations on the same matrix. So I need to link all the value from the matrix ==> so inside the matrix I need "relative reference" once the matrix in on I need "absolute reference"

Comment: I apologize, I'm having difficulty understanding what you mean, perhaps it is a language barrier?

Comment: Why do you need to fix the references? You may have your reasons, but this strikes me as unnecessary once you have the data on the sheet.